# sendmail uses too much cpu

Tags: fedora, sendmail

I am running Fedora 31 and time to time I get high CPU for dozen of seconds randomly during the time like every ten minutes or so that is caused by `sendmail`.

So far I am not able find out why.

Can you help me to find what is the root cause of it and how to prevent it. Momentarily I am not aware of any service/job that could run that process. It happens in computer idle state as well.

Here is my observation so far my:

When the usage of CPU is high I can `ps faux | grep sendmail`

```
ps faux | grep sendmail
/usr/bin/bash /usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -i -odi -oem -oi -t -f <username>
```

Process `which sendmail`

```
$ which sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail
$ ls -la /usr/sbin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar  3 11:14 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta
$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/mta
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Mar  3 11:14 /etc/alternatives/mta -> /usr/bin/esmtp-wrapper
$ ls -la /usr/bin/esmtp-wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3378 Jul 25  2019 /usr/bin/esmtp-wrapper
$ ls -la /usr/bin/esmtp-wrapper
```

I tried see `mail`

```
$ mail 
No mail for <username>
```

All files in `var/spool/mail/` are empty, `/var/log/maillog` is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/bash /usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -i -odi -oem -oi -t -f <username>
```

`<username>` is probably running a cron job. Perhaps it's running every ten minutes or so, and doing something that consumes a noticeable amount of CPU each time.

This sendmail process looks like it is started by `cron` to email the output of the cron job. The resulting email normally goes to `/var/mail/<username>`, but the cron job could direct it to some possibly remote email address instead.

What is the output of `crontab -l -u <username>`?

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I had a job scheduled */10 minutes that runs a .sh script on path that does not exists.
I have disabled that job and CPU usage seems to be flattered since then.
I just wonder how this could raise CPU for about 30 seconds and no other output/log details can be found... Anyway I will monitor it if it was real root cause or not. 
Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!